# PHP: How to use the content of $_POST variable for SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, string

I am using a drop-down list in the source php file for users to choose a US state.  In the action.php, the selected state can be successfully received by the following code, confirmed by echo:

```
<?php
$state_chosen = $_POST['state_chosen']; 
echo $state_chosen;
?>
```

My question is: How to use the content of the **$state_chosen** variable in sql query.  Use the following code and the state of Maine as example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pathjobs WHERE loc_pj LIKE '%Maine%' ";
```

The above code works fine if use "Maine" directly.  But I want to use the content of **$state_chosen** to replace "Maine" between the two % symbols.  I tried the following code by doesn't work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pathjobs WHERE loc_pj LIKE '%str($state_chosen)%' ";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `'%$state_chosen%'` check now

Comment: It works!  As simple as that!  I didn't even try it because I thought $state_chosen would be considered as string instead of variable.  Could you please add it as an answer instead of comment?  So I can mark it as the favored answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM pathjobs WHERE loc_pj LIKE '%str($state_chosen)%' ";`

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pathjobs WHERE loc_pj LIKE '%$state_chosen%' ";
```

[Like query documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: You should not forget to mention SQL injection here.

Comment: @Gumbo Can you Edit it

Comment: If $state_chosen is only from a pulldown menu with ONLY preset choices, do I still need to worry about SQL injection?